# HttpWebRequest and Uri change requestUri

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, uri

I have one problem with HttpWebRequest and Uri class of .NET framework (i use 3.5 version). When i try to do a simple request to page with url like this http://somedomain.net/-hello-world:misc./Items.bok, Uri remove "." before  last "/". Is there any ability to prevent it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that this is a known issue, but unfortunately remains unsolved. This was discussed a few months ago in the following Stack Overflow post:

- [HttpWebRequest to URL with dot at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856885/httpwebrequest-to-url-with-dot-at-the-end)

---

From [.NET Framework Dev Center - Bug in Uri class with periods](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/5206beca-071f-485d-a2bd-657d635239c9/):

> This is a known bug.  This was actually discussed on these forums not
>   too long ago.  An MSFT employee
>   acknowledged the problem and stated
>   that it will be considered for a
>   future release.