# how to create a Uri with "."

Tags: c#-4.0, escaping, uri, invalid-characters

I have a string with "." like https://mysite.com/Relation=My.Test.AL.?Path=MySymbolPath
when I create uri from it 
the "." is truncated. https://mysite.com/Relation=My.Test.AL?Path=MySymbolPath

```
    var uristring = "https://mysite.com/Relation=My.Test.AL.?Path=MySymbolPath";
    var uri = new Uri(Uri.EscapeUriString(uristring ));
```

See uristring has "AL.", but uri.AbsoluteUri does not, it has "AL" 
Do you know how to prevent it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a known bug in .NET framework. 
Workaround exists.  Thanks 
see 
[HttpWebRequest to URL with dot at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856885/httpwebrequest-to-url-with-dot-at-the-end)

[How to create a Uri instance parsed with GenericUriParserOptions.DontCompressPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515959/how-to-create-a-uri-instance-parsed-with-genericuriparseroptions-dontcompresspat)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/5206beca-071f-485d-a2bd-657d635239c9

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/386695/system-uri-incorrectly-strips-trailing-dots