# C# HttpWebRequest problem

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HttpWebRequest to URL with dot at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856885/httpwebrequest-to-url-with-dot-at-the-end)

I am facing a weird problem. When I am trying to get a page using HttpWebRequest page is not coming properly. The url has a dot into it like **http://www.xyz.com/abc./do** . You can see this url has a dot into it. So when I am trying fetching that data using HttpWebRequest data is not coming properly. So I tracked it with fiddler and I saw this class omitting the dot like **http://www.xyz.com/abc/do** . How can I solve this problem ?

NB. This is not a real url. But the problem is real.

Comment: as I can see you are missing forward slash it should be http://

Comment: Sorry another type mistake. I have modified it.

Comment: Yeah sure. http://www.automatica-munich.com/exvi/en/bfa_solutions_ltd./CH/A1/328

Comment: I've tried to open it in my browser and it doesn't work...

Comment: @Senad Meškin: Sorry that is not a real url. I am just trying to express my problem.

Comment: can you post a code you are using ?

Comment: I'm able to navigate to the URL @Barun provided with IE9, Chrome 12, and FF4.  I would normally argue that the URL is not correctly formatted and therefore I wouldn't expect the HttpWebRequest to accept it - however, the browsers don't seem to mind it.

Comment: Interesting - I can't find any other problems like this - nor cna I find a way (so far) to prevent the address being parsed and the "." being removed.  You can't escape the character obviously, and even if you try Uri x = new Uri("http://www.automatica-munich.com/exvi/en/bfa_solutions_ltd./CH/A1/328"); you'll see the same behaviour. I still think the URL provided is badly formatted, but no idea how to handle it...

Comment: Well found @Jamiec.  That _should_ do the trick, and it figures that it's an MS bug.  I wouldn't say it's a duplicate simply due to the positioning of the dots - one being trailing, one being mid-address. Anyone with time fancy checking if this particular case is a _valid_ Url?

Comment: Its a valid url for browsers, and the workaround in the linked question does work with this url. I tested it but im not putting an answer here as its just the same thing.

Comment: What are you guyz talking about ?

Comment: @Barun see the question Jameic linked.  That solution should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

may be encoding url solve the problem

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncodeUnicode(url)
```

Comment: `.` is a valid url character, and therefore won't be encoded by the method call above.