# WebClient returns 404 error, but this url works in the WebBrowser.Navigate method

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, uri, webclient

I try to download a html file using `WebClient`.

This is my code:

```
public string GetWebData(string url)
{
        string html = string.Empty;

        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            Uri innUri = null;
            Uri.TryCreate(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out innUri);

            try
            {
                client.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", " en-US");
                client.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
                client.Headers.Add("Accept", " text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*");
                client.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)");

                using (StreamReader str = new StreamReader(client.OpenRead(innUri)))
                {
                    html = str.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            catch (WebException we)
            {
                throw we;
            }

            return html;
        }
    }
```

The URL is  `http://www.paginegialle.it/roma-rm/abbigliamento/alberto-aspesi-c`.

[image]

But I can navigate to this URL in IE9 and Firefox and Chrome browsers without problem. I use  Fiddler to solve this problem.

I find the URL has changed after the `WebClient.Request` - see the image below:

Actual url: `http://www.paginegialle.it/roma-rm/abbigliamento/alberto-aspesi-c.`

[image]

[image]

Please see the difference. I remove the dot in at the end of the url. But it's not working in the browsers (IE9, Firefox, Chrome). How to change the actual url to this url?

Please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HttpWebRequest to URL with dot at the end](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856885/httpwebrequest-to-url-with-dot-at-the-end)

Answer (score 0):

is the web address still correct after this line:

```
     Uri.TryCreate(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out innUri);
```

I'm guessing it works for other sites?

Comment: Thank you for your valueable reply. 

Please see this image [image] https://blufiles.storage.live.com/y1pZ77S7y4AIiEoW6NKKrBx1oKRVXoKoZ7u04P2IWZrauutal7L2Lj4Mg/Url%20Change%20%20After%20url%20conversion.png.jpg?psid=1&ck=0&ex=720

Answer (score 0):

I think you've found a cool bug in the .NET URI object.

```
MessageBox.Show(new Uri("http://example.com/bug/here."));
```

shows:

> http://example.com/bug/here

Note that the trailing period is missing.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856885/httpwebrequest-to-url-with-dot-at-the-end