# URL trailing period is swallowed by HttpListener

Tags: c#, windows, webdav, explorer, httplistener

I have created an `System.Net.HttpListener`-based *WebDav* server to provide access to a(n existing) document library stored in a database through a virtual file system. The purpose of this component is to provide a file-level access to the stored documents which can be attached as a network drive under Windows, so using a different client is out of the question.

The database stores the documents in a file system-like hierarchy, so I mapped the containers as WebDav collections (which in clients show up as folders), and everything seemed nice until I found out my users use collections which has trailing periods in their names. Please note, that this is a product which is in production for more than a decade, so introducing new naming conventions is out of the question. Since HttpListener uses the standard C# `System.Uri` class to provide the request URL, and that class swallows trailing periods of URLs.

```
https://www.something.com/xyz.
```

for example becomes

```
https://www.something.com/xyz
```

It would be bad enough in itself, but it could be solved by also checking for the period-extended folder name. But the problem is a lot worse than that, because the `System.Uri` class does not only mutilates the last segment of the path, but all of them, so

```
https://www.something.com/xyz./knm/xxx.doc
```

becomes

```
https://www.something.com/xyz/knm/xxx.doc
```

and

```
https://www.something.com/xyz./knm/./qwe./xyz.doc
```

becomes

```
https://www.something.com/xyz/knm/qwe/xyz.doc
```

which I have no way to handle.

what I have tried so far...

- Escaping the period by replacing it with "%2E" doe not work, because it doesn't get unescaped in clients like Windows Explorer and Total Commander.
- Returning an escaped version in the PROPFIND href node and a literal version in the dislpayname node does not work, because "displayname" is ignored by most clients.
- The workaround described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2285321/2144232) doesn't seem to work. (It doesn't do anything. Another answer in the same thread provides a way to hack a certain instance of the `System.Uri` class, but since the instance is created by the HttpListener - or one of its underlying mechanisms - that really does no help for me.)

In a thread from like 2008 I have found the following quote

> This is a known bug.  This was actually discussed on these forums not too long ago.  An MSFT employee acknowledged the problem and stated that it will be considered for a future release.

Can anybody provide a workaround or actual solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of .NET Framework are you using?
I created a sample app and initialized a System.URI with string containing dots. .NET 4.0 removed the dots, but anything newer left them in.

Can you use a newer version of .NET?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/one./two./three./my.doc");

        Console.WriteLine(uri.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, my target framework was .NET 4.0. Sadly I can't use a newer one yet, but we plan to move further in the near future.